# OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_RECORD', 'decryption failed or bad record mac')]

Tags: ssl, github, bitbucket, git-bash

i am trying to clone a repository from bit bucket which sharing by other member of our group...but fetch an error during cloning...

```
 Cloning into 'industryprime'...
   Password for 'https://abhragh@bitbucket.org':
remote: Counting objects: 20143, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5741/5741), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:1408F119:SSL     routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

what can i do?

Comment: Aren't you using Debian? I heard that it's a debian related issue

Comment: I had same problem. I restarted my computer and everythings works fine again. I think it was something with fireware or anti virus...